# Summing up double lists in a Linq GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I need to group a large number of records which were recorded every minute into daily and bind them to a chart. These records have two fields the `datetime` value and the `double list`. I've tried something like this:

```
var result = Alldatas
  .AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(r => r.TimeStamp.Day)
  .Select(x => new {
                 Day = x.Key,
                 Value = x.Sum(r => r.Value.Sum())
          })
  .OrderBy(x => x.Day)
  .ToList();
```

The problem is that the list items in the `double list` is being summed up each other into a single double value. The correct result is that `double lists` should be adding up each other into a single `double list` for each day. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: `Value = x.SelectMany(r => r.Value)`

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for the response. But this only selects a minutes worth of `Values`, whereas the `Values` should be the total of each day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, here is the code:

```
var result = Alldatas
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.TimeStamp.Day)
    .Select(x => new {
        Day = x.Key,
        // Using Aggregate method
        Value = x
            .Select(y => y.Value)
            .Aggregate(new List<double>(), (acc, list) =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
                {
                    if (acc.Count == i) acc.Add(0);
                    acc[i] += list[i];
                }

                return acc;
        }),
        // Pure LINQ, using GroupBy
        Value2 = x
            // Create tuple (index, value) for each double
            .SelectMany(y => y.Value.Select((z, i) => Tuple.Create(i, z)))
            // Group by index
            .GroupBy(y => y.Item1)
            // Sum values within groups
            .Select(y => y.Select(z => z.Item2).Sum())
            // Make list
            .ToList()
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Day)
    .ToList();
```

For input:

```
var Alldatas = new []
{
    new { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Value = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 } },
    new { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Value = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 } },
    new { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Value = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 } }
};
```

This will produce following result:

```
new[] {
    new { Day = 20, Value = new[] {3,6,9}, Value2 = new[] {3,6,9} }
}
```

Comment: Plus one for understanding the problem :)

Comment: I was looking for a way to get the real `datetime` value for the `Date` variable. Currently, the `Day = x.Key` code is only returning the date part.

Comment: I got it. I just change the `GroupBy(r => r.TimeStamp.Day)` to `GroupBy(r => r.TimeStamp.Date)`.